# Is it worth cleaning ThreadLocals in Filter to solve thread pool-related issues?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

In short - tomcat uses a thread pool, so threads are reused. Some libraries use `ThreadLocal` variables, but don't clean them up (using `.remove()`), so in fact they return "dirty" threads to the pool.

Tomcat has new features of detecting these things on shutdown, and cleaning the thread locals. But it means the threads are "dirty" during the whole execution.

What I can do is implement a `Filter`, and right after the request completes (and the thread is returned to the pool), clean all `ThreadLocal`s, using the [code from tomcat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_8/java/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.java) (the method there is called `checkThreadLocalsForLeaks`).

The question is, is it worth it? Two pros:

- preventing memory leaks
- preventing undeterministic behaviour by the libraries, which assume the thread is "fresh"

One con:

- The solution uses reflection, so it's potentially slow. All reflection data (`Field`s) will be cached, of course, but still.

Another option is to report the issue to the libraries that don't clean their thread locals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go through the route of reporting the issue to the library developers for 2 reasons:

- It will help to other people who want to use the same library, but lack the skills / time to find such a HORRIBLE memory leak.
- To help the developers of the library to build a better product.

Honestly, I've never seen this type of error before and I think it's an exception rather than something that we should guard as it happens often. Could you share on which library you've seen this behaviour?

As a side note, I wouldn't mind enabling that filter in the development / test environment and logging a critical error if a ThreadLocal variable is still attached.

Comment: it's not just one library, that's the problem. Cleaning up thread locals appears to be done rarely.

Comment: Failing to clean up a ThreadLocal is not generally a memory leak - for example if you're using a ThreadLocal<Integer> the space taken up with the Integer will be negligible compared to the space taken with the rest of the Thread's resources. It's only an issue if the library assumes the ThreadLocal is empty at the start of each request.

Comment: I think you got confused, we're not talking about the size of a thread local related to what is stored, but how it produces a memory leak (of the whole classloader) when a web application is **unloaded**. Also the scenario of just storing a simple class is not so common. Usually you'll have a framework, such as spring, putting a few objects in thread locals.

Answer (score 1):

in theory, this seems like a good idea.  however, i could see some situations where you might *not* want to do this.  for instance, some of the xml related technologies have some non-trivial setup costs (like setting up DocumentBuilders and Transformers).  if you are doing a *lot* of that in your webapp, it may make sense to cache these instances in ThreadLocals (as the utilities are generally not thread-safe).  in this case, you probably don't want to clean these between requests.

Comment: even if there is some side-effect benefit, I don't think it should be abused like that.

Comment: @Bozho, why do you see that as an abuse?  it's more like a cheap object pool.

Comment: because you are never sure that a given library does everything properly. Better safe than sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you think there's a chance that the dirtiness of the threads will actually cause problems, then this is a sensible thing to do. Problems are to be avoided where possible.

The use of threadlocals may be bad behaviour by the library, and you should certainly report it to the authors, but sadly, right now, it's down to you to deal with it.

I wouldn't worry too much about performance. The slow bit in reflection is the metadata lookup; once you have a Field object, then using it is fairly quick, and gets quicker over time - AIUI, it starts out working by making a native call into the JVM, but after some number of uses, it generates bytecode for the access, which can then be compiled into native code, optimised, inlined, etc, so it shouldn't be much slower than a direct field access. I don't think the Tomcat code reuses the Field objects across requests, though, so if you want to take advantage of that, you'd have to write your own cleaning code. In any case, the performance cost will be far smaller than the cost of the IO associated with the request.