# Error when starting/stopping Tomcat 6.0.29

Tags: spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have configured some schedulers in spring.When i try to start my web application it throws following error and stops.My application is not actually started.My scheduler looks something like this also when i shut down tomcat some quartz thread are not shut down

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
           <ref bean="scheduler.localAdaptorCronTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>   

<bean id="localAdaptor" class="LocalAdaptor" />

<bean id="scheduler.localFSSlaAdaptorJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="Adaptor"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="xxxxxx"/>
</bean>

<bean id="scheduler.localAdaptorCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduler.localAdaptorJobDetail"/>
        <!-- run every morning at 12 AM -->
      <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="scheduler.localFSSlaAdaptorSimpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
        <!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="scheduler.localAdaptorJobDetail"/>
        <!-- runs after 10 seconds for single time...-->
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000"/>
        <!-- repeated once -->
        <property name="repeatCount" value="0"/>
        <!-- useless as the repeat count is 0, so it will run once after 10 seconds of the startup of the application.... -->
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="60000"/>
</bean>
```

Stacktrace:

```
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/c] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 31, 2011 10:02:22 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@71ee88dd]) and a value of type [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl] (value [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl@409468ca]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I implemented listener:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
 import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
 import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
 import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


 public class QuartzServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

     final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzServletContextListener.class);
     public static final String QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY =
             "org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY";
     private ServletContext ctx = null;
     private StdSchedulerFactory factory = null;

     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
         ctx = sce.getServletContext();

         try {

             factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

             // Start the scheduler now

             factory.getScheduler().start();

             log.info("Storing QuartzScheduler Factory at"
                     + QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);

             ctx.setAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY, factory);

         } catch (Exception ex) {
             log.error("Quartz failed to initialize", ex);
         }
     }

     public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
         try {

             log.info("shutting down");
             factory.getScheduler().shutdown();
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             log.error("Quartz failed to shutdown", ex);
         } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
             log.error("Quartz failed to shutdown", ex);
         }
     }
 }
```

And added in web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>xx.yy.QuartzServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

When I try to use shutdown.sh I can se still some threads active and tomcat java process active .

Also to mention I have some 3 to 4 schedulers for different job as mentioned above in application context.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899205/tomcat-6-memory-leaks-log-entries

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054265/is-it-worth-cleaning-threadlocals-in-filter-to-solve-thread-pool-related-issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for any Quartz-related resources being reported by Tomcat, this is due to Tomcat being a bit over-eager at looking for non-freed resources when Quartz takes more than a few milliseconds to shutdown its resources.

See discussion here (along with a simple work-around):

http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/3479.page

Comment: thank you it solved the problem.I also implemented a listener to shutdow

Comment: This is not a problem in Tomcat. Even if the threads are about to terminate, there is no way of knowing. Therefore threads should probably be interrupted and joined before completely unloading the servlet. This is described in another answer. It is a good thing that Tomcat warns about this.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a problem. Tomcat automatically removes the unwanted threads and threadlocals, but just tells you that your code or libraries are doing something "risky".

You may want to report issues to the respective libraries (c3p0 and CXF) that they should cleanup on shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that threads are terminated, is to interrupt and join them.

This can by done by implementing [`org.quartz.InterruptableJob`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/InterruptableJob.html), as described in the answer to the question [*How to prevent a memory leak in quartz [?]*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704418/how-to-prevent-a-memory-leak-in-quartz/15269920#15269920).